# How can we compare three integers to find which one is bigger/smaller?

Tags: javascript, variables, comparison

For example; we have three variables:

```
var a = 11;
var b = 23;
var c = 8;
```

Can we return the variable name of the biggest/smallest value?

Comment: If you could get the variable `name`, what would you do with said `name`?

Comment: Is it really important that you know the *name* of the variable?

Comment: No, not really. Maybe i can use it in an eval function. But i can live without it anyway.

Comment: If all you need is a max or min value then [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) are what you require.

Comment: If you need to know the name of the variable, it seems like you're doing something wrong, or that you'd be better off having a lookup object with name/value pairs instead of `var a, b, c;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably need to use an object or an array to know the variable's name :

```
var obj = {
    'a':11,
    'b':23,
    'c':8
};

var biggest = '';
for (var name in obj) {
    if(biggest !== '' && obj[name] > obj[biggest]) {
        biggest = name;
    } else if (biggest === '') {
        biggest = name;
    }
}
return biggest;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.max(a, b, c)
```

If you have variable number of items in an array:

```
var arr = [a, b, c];
Math.max.apply(null, arr);
```

Comment: He wants the variable name I think, ie 'b'.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the variables names of the smallest and largest values that you require, then using ECMA5 methods you could do something like this. You will need to use an `object` to be able to get names rather than individual variables.

Javascript

```
function getNamesSmallestToLargestByValue(thisObj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function (name) {
        return [name, this[name]];
    }, thisObj).sort(function (x, y) {
        return x[1] - y[1];
    }).map(function (element) {
        return element.shift();
    });
}

var obj = {
        'a': 11,
        'b': 23,
        'c': 8
    };

console.log(getNamesSmallestToLargestByValue(obj));
```

Output

```
["c", "a", "b"]
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/rRANT/)

As you can see, the returned array will give you the names sorted from smallest to largest by their associated values. Therefore the first element is the name of the smallest value and last element is the name of the largest value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('sco').value);

var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('sce').value);

var z = parseInt(document.getElementById('scm').value);

if (x > y && x > z)
{
document.getElementById('yo').innerHTML = 'x is greater';
}

else if (y > x && y > z){
document.getElementById('yo').innerHTML = 'y is greater';
}

else{
document.getElementById('yo').innerHTML = 'z is greater';
}
```