# Find which variable has smallest value

Tags: javascript

I have three variables like below

```
x = 3;
y = 1;
z = 2;
```

How do i get the smallest one ? That is y.

Right now I do it like below

```
if(x < y && x < z)
{
var smallest = x;
}
else if(y < x && y < z)
{
var smallest = y;
}
else if(z < x && z < y)
{
var smallest = z;
}
```

Any other smart way to do it ?

P.S : I need to get that variable name.

Comment: Math.min(x,y,z)

Comment: `Math.min(Math.min(x,y),z)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Math.min() to return the variable name instead of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634854/how-to-get-math-min-to-return-the-variable-name-instead-of-a-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Math.min can be good option in this case

```js
x = 3;
y = 1;
z = 2;

console.log(Math.min(x, y, z))
```

And if you want variable name too you can use object instead as described in this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23547432/9133104)

```js
var obj = {
  "x": 3,
  "y": 1,
  "z": 2
};

var smallest = '';
for (var key in obj) {
  if (smallest !== '' && obj[key] < obj[smallest]) {
    smallest = key;
  } else if (smallest === '') {
    smallest = key;
  }
}
console.log("smallest---", smallest);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var smallest_value = Math.min( x, y, z);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let x = 3, y = 1, z = 2;
let minArr = Object.entries({x, y, z}).sort((arr1, arr2) => {
    return arr1[1] - arr2[1];
}).shift();

console.log(`min: key is "${minArr[0]}", value is ${minArr[1]}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have in this way

```
Math.min(x,y,z,..)
```

Below can be useful if you have large data set in your application.
Then you can use in this way

```
var numArray = [1, 2, 3]
Math.min.apply(Math, numArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your input the best possible way I think is your own code.
But if the input is of the form of an `array` or some `dictionary` you can easily find the `smallest number` by simply looping them and can update the index (in case of an array) or you get the `key` in case of `dictionary`.
e.g.,
`array = (1,2,3,0,4,5,6)
 smallest = 0 and its Index=4
 now you get the index then you can get the variable name, say 
 var1 = Index 1, var2 = Index 2 and so on..`

You have to make some changes just to make your work done.

In case of dictionary you can directly get the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Math.min(value1,value2,.....),but if still you want to use the conventional method you can follow the below link to see the code written.

`let x = 100,y=200,z=30,min = '';
    min = x < y && x < z ? 'x = '+x :y<z ?'y = '+y : 'z = '+z;`

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G58KSEBOL67M

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
var x = 6;
var y = 7;
var z = 4;

for(o in window){ 
  if(window[o] === Math.min(x,y,z)){
    console.log(o);
   }
}
```